# VBA Code doesn't read in String correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the midfunction method to read a character combination. I want to use the read character combination as a filter for another spreadsheet. But the character combination is not found.
In the textbox the character combination is output correctly.

Sourcecode:

```
Sub TemplateNummerFinden()
    m_cstrTemplate = ActiveCell.Value
    Dim strTemplateNummer As String
    
    strTemplateNummer = Mid(m_cstrTemplate, 14)
    MsgBox "Template Nummer: " & strTemplateNummer
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=strTemplateNummer, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: To get 1 character you need `strTemplateNummer = Mid(m_cstrTemplate, 14, 1)` unless `m_cstrTemplate` is exactly 14 characters long

Comment: @SuperSymmetry OP tries to read a *"character combination"* so `Mid(m_cstrTemplate, 14)` reads everthing from the 14ᵗʰ character until the end of the string.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I guess my brain stopped at "*a character*" and filtered out "*combination*" even though OP repeated it 4 times. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Criteria1:=strTemplateNummer` looks for the **exact match**. If you want to find every entry that **contains** the characters you need to add placeholders:

```
Criteria1:="*" & strTemplateNummer & "*"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
but even if i use 'Criteria1:="*" & strTemplateNumber & "*"" i get no results in filtering

Comment: This should work. The fact that you have `strTemplateNumber` in your comment vs `strTemplateNummer` in your code suggests variable name typos in your code. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all your variables and **hopefully** this will be the issue.

Comment: Also note that the answer is suggesting `"*" & strTemplateNummer & "*"`. i.e. concatenating an astrisk (`*`) before and after you string. In your comment above you have an empty string. Please try to copy and paste the code from the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it correctly in the code, just misspelled it in my comment

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces in the end or beginning `Criteria1:="*" & Trim$(strTemplateNummer) & "*"`. If that does not work please give us the result of `Debug.Print """" & strTemplateNummer & """"` in the immediate window.